# how to configure Bluetooth peripheral device with advertisement data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to configure the values for the advertisement data keys like CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey,CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey,etc.

I need to set values for the above keys from the central device.

Is there any way to do that?

thanks in advance...

Comment: No, those values are set in the peripheral when it advertises. And even then you can't set the power level. See the CBPeripheralManager documentation. Instead of repeatedly asking the same bad question in different ways you should explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit the advertisement data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077395/how-to-edit-the-advertisement-data)